# ZeroMQ Majordomo Pattern

Tags: zeromq

In the Majordomo pattern, a section of code in the worker looks like this

```
mdwrk session ("tcp://localhost:5555", sourceStr.c_str(), verbose);

zmsg *reply = 0;
while (1) {
    zmsg *request = session.recv (reply);
    if (request == 0) {
        break;              //  Worker was interrupted
    }

    //reply = request;        //  Echo is complex... :-)
    reply = new zmsg(sourceStr.c_str());
}
```

To my worker, the request from the client is an order to be sent to an exchange. I am trying to wrap my head around how, after I send the order to the exchange, and I get a message back like, Insert, Pending, New, etc, I can stuff the contents of the FIX response, into zmsg *reply.

The FIX message comes back asynchrously, so I won't be able to say

reply = FIXResponse;

How is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Majordomo protocol is meant to handle synchronous requests and not really appropriate here.

Just came across one of your other questions, and see that you have multiple sources for these replies. You could PUSH them all into a single stable PULL socket? (And then republish if appropriate. If the volume is low, you could even get away with durable subscribers for reliability.)

Comment: I mispoke when I said it wasn't synchronous. It simple happens on a callback. In any event, I asked Peiter here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179061/right-zeromq-topology and he said to use Majordomo?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it can't be synchronous because FIX is inherently not synchronous. For example, you submit an order, and the FIX engine may send you the following consecutive messages just for that order, Insert, Pending, New, Partial Fill, etc...

Comment: In that other post you didn't really mention asynchronous requests. I'm not familiar enough with Majordomo to speak in absolutes, but PUSH/PULL should work. Just make sure that callback is using a thread local socket.

Comment: Can Push/Pull sockets have an identity? There can be many clients and workers (using Majordomo language), and when I send the order to a particular exchange, and messages come back from the worker, I need to know which client to send those messages to. So I need to route on the way to a worker, and I need to route on the way back to the client. The nice thing about Majordomo is that all of that was taken care for me, with a broker in between. I guess the single PULL socket would be acting as a broker in your example.